# Search matching keywords in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get the matched keywords from SQL 2008 database?

My datatype is nvarchar and text.If I search `"blind"` from the below text it should return `"BLINDING"`

Text example:

```
"you will learn how to recognize clinical conditions that can be LETHAL and those that can be BLINDING."
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Please try and clarify your question, it's not clear at all what you are trying to achieve and where your problem is.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a string percent match or fuzzy lookup?

Comment: I have column in sql server table called description which has the text for example "you will learn how to recognize clinical conditions that can be LETHAL and those that can be BLINDING." Now I want to find matching keywords in that text based on my input. So, if I try to search for 'blind' it should return "BLINDING" as ouput.

Comment: Remove the "mysql" tag unless it somehow relates to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and not so helpful comment. I think what you're trying to do is search a table for values when when only putting partial values and try and match those partial values, this is also known as a fuzzy lookup.

Using SQL you could write a query like this to get your result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Value like 'BLIND%';
```

From a table set up as below:

```
Name    Date    Value
A   1/1/2015    BLINDING
A   1/1/2015    BLINDER
A   1/1/2015    BLENDER
A   1/1/2015    LETHAL
A   1/1/2015    BINDER
```

You would return:

```
A   1/1/2015    BLINDING
A   1/1/2015    BLINDER
```

Comment: BLINDING is not a single value in my column, it's a part of the text below "you will learn how to recognize clinical conditions that can be LETHAL and those that can be BLINDING."

Comment: So if that's your value what do you want to return?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want if it's a string like that without returning the entire value in the column, what you could do is return a flag of 0 or 1 whether or not the value is present in the string or not and then parse the string...let me try and do this .